# Corrupted File from PHP Header File returned from database?

Tags: php, header

I have the following function that gets a blob from the database and should return the file to the browser, however it is returning a corrupt file:

`$file_data` is an array with the returned row from the files table with the blob, the content type, last modified and other such things.

`$data` is the `blob` component of the $file_data array.

```
function header_file($data, $file_data)
            {
                $last_modified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $file_data['unix_last_modified_time'])." GMT";


                // if browser question if it's up to date
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']))
                {
                    // parse header
                    $if_modified_since = preg_replace('/;.*$/', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']);

                    if ($if_modified_since == $last_modified)
                    {
                        // the browser's cache is still up to date
                        header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
                        header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate");
                        exit;
                    }
                }

                header("Cache-Control: max-age=86400, must-revalidate");
                header("Last-Modified: ".$last_modified);
                header("Content-Type: ".$file_data['file_upload_type']);
                // this prevents caching...
                // yea, lots of hair lost to this one...
                //header("Content-Length: " . strlen($data));
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

                if($file_data['file_upload_type'] == 'application/x-shockwave-flash')
                    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"".str_replace(' ','_',$file_data['file_upload_name'])."\"");
                else
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".str_replace(' ','_',$file_data['file_upload_name'])."\"");

                // send data to output
                echo $data;
                exit;
            }
```

Before the function is run, the output buffer is cleared with:

```
if(ob_get_length() > 0) 
            {
                ob_clean();
            }
```

**Results:**

File downloads, with the correct filesize however it is corrupted.Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768650/zend-caching-of-images-gives-problems-once-the-site-goes-down-for-a-while

**Response:**

```
Request URL:http://www.example.com/index.php?module=uploads&sub_module=getfile&id=4982
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:banner89=yes; banner90=yes; PHPSESSID=vhlk92ihtcdmtv2q4vhjbmsv54; __utmz=45276912.1383308583.8.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utma=45276912.1890999283.1366697926.1383574554.1383631349.15; __utmc=45276912
DNT:1
Host:www.example.com
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
module:uploads
sub_module:getfile
id:4982
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:max-age=86400, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Masthead-Banner.gif"
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:5920
Content-Type:image/gif
Date:Tue, 05 Nov 2013 09:14:03 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Tue, 05 Nov 2013 08:27:55 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Cache:MISS from firewall.
```

**More investigation:**

Opening the downloaded file and comparing it with the one on the server reveals that the header and footer of the text is the same but there are a lots of characters that are different:

Real Thing:

````
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
165 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 100758/O 167/E 86272/N 4/T 100409/H [ 498 245]>>
endobj

181 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<47941C1B25C34A4EA92EE88606328B32><09EC517E475E964EB1CBEF770BC3C54D>]/Index[165 33]/Info 164 0 R/Length 91/Prev 100410/Root 166 0 R/Size 198/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream
hÞbbd```b``º"§I~É"Á²`Ä¹,«æ*H®(;D&L@ÿí¿Hþßø  h   XÊäF¯O  ~O
7
endstream
endobj
startxref
0
%%EOF

197 0 obj
<</C 163/Filter/FlateDecode/I 185/Length 151/O 147/S 94>>stream
hÞb```¢vV3A Ç%êzÅ¯ K    ULT«Ú1Q5}ukGGGGFGG#Ã#>(f`dàg¬áú¨}À!óÆÄF ?O1x7°30ínÒ@ôHs00íÍa ;Sn$Óu¨*E  »!S
endstream
endobj
166 0 obj
<</MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 10 0 R/Outlines 14 0 R/PageLayout/OneColumn/Pages 163 0 R/StructTreeRoot 25 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
167 0 obj
<</Contents 171 0 R/CropBox[0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]/MediaBox[0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]/Parent 163 0 R/Resources<</ColorSpace<</CS0 182 0 R/CS1 183 0 R>>/Font<</C2_0 188 0 R/TT0 190 0 R/TT1 192 0 R/TT2 194 0 R/TT3 196 0 R>>>>/Rotate 0/StructParents 0/Type/Page>>
endobj
168 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 121/Length 1269/N 15/Type/ObjStm>>stream
````

Corrupted:

````
%PDF-1.5
%âãÏÓ
165 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 100758/O 167/E 86272/N 4/T 100409/H [ 498 245]>>
endobj

181 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 5/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<47941C1B25C34A4EA92EE88606328B32><09EC517E475E964EB1CBEF770BC3C54D>]/Index[165 33]/Info 164 0 R/Length 91/Prev 100410/Root 166 0 R/Size 198/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream
hÞbbd```b``º"§‚I~É"™Á²`Ä¹,«æ*ƒH®(™;D&L‘@’‘ÿˆí¿Hþßø™ h‹  X–‘ÊäF¯O  ~O
7
endstream
endobj
startxref
0
%%EOF

197 0 obj
<</C 163/Filter/FlateDecode/I 185/Length 151/O 147/S 94>>stream
hÞb```¢vV3AŠ Ç†%êŒzŽÅ–¯ K   ™ULT«Ú1Q5}ukGGGGƒFGG#Ã•#>(f`dàg¬‘áú¨}Àœ!“‹óÆÄF  †—?O1x7€•°30ínÒŒ@ôHs00íÍa ;•Sn$Óu¨*E€  »!S
endstream
endobj
166 0 obj
<</MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 10 0 R/Outlines 14 0 R/PageLayout/OneColumn/Pages 163 0 R/StructTreeRoot 25 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
167 0 obj
<</Contents 171 0 R/CropBox[0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]/MediaBox[0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]/Parent 163 0 R/Resources<</ColorSpace<</CS0 182 0 R/CS1 183 0 R>>/Font<</C2_0 188 0 R/TT0 190 0 R/TT1 192 0 R/TT2 194 0 R/TT3 196 0 R>>>>/Rotate 0/StructParents 0/Type/Page>>
endobj
168 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 121/Length 1269/N 15/Type/ObjStm>>stream
````

**More info:**

PDF's are now downloading correctly...fiddled around but never changed anything, always `ctrl +z`

**latest Revelations:**

A space is added to the top of files which corrupts the image...However i don't know how to get rid of it programmatically.

Comment: So what _is_ actually sent to the browser? Are we meant to _guess_?

Comment: have you verified that the correct data are saved to db?

Comment: I updated, but that does not answer my question, sorry. "It is corrupted" can mean a million of things or nothing at all. So what _is_ sent?

Comment: Yes, 100% correct in the database

Comment: Listen mate don't want to get into a shouting match, if you check the link you can find the returned data. I'll add it to the question in case.

Comment: Some more Information my friend...@arkascha

Comment: `$data` is received as parameter, the function does not fetch it. I assume you've double-checked its value (e.g., dumping it into a file).

Comment: Yes i have dumped it, as shown above, it is the same as the downloaded file. ie. corrupted. Comparing it with the real thing shows there are quite a few differences.

Comment: So maybe the data got corrupted already on _storing_ it into the database – go check that.

Comment: No the data stored in the database is 100% perfect

Comment: Check my latest discoveries: a pdf file downloads no problem, and all the other files are corrupt. The reason the other files are corrupt is because a return character (enter "/n") is added at the top of the returned corrupted file. Why is this happening? how can it be solved?

Comment: Found the Problem: End of Line characters....Unix/Linux: '\n' (The server)...Windows: '\r\n' (My Machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with Windows and Unix Line Endings because it is a unix based web server the `\cr\lf` applies where just the `\lf` should. Hence the images are being rendered with a space at the beginning which corrupts the entire file.